# Can't use an Add-on in Google Spreadsheet with Google Workspace

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

I have installed an Add-on for Google spreadsheet with a Google Workspace account. But unlike spreadsheet with Gmail account, I can't see the Add-on under "Add-ons" menu in Spreadsheet.

I checked the admin console and confirmed that the app is installed. (See attached screenshot.)
https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/gmail/marketplace/domaininstall

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB5R6.png)

Could you somebody advise how I can use the add-on with Spreadsheet?

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours to propagate. Have you waited the 24 hours?

Comment: Marti, thanks for the comment. Yes, I waited for a few days already but still can't see the add-on in the menu.

Comment: Then try the following: Click to the app row, then click `Distribution` and make sure that it's `ON for everyone`

Comment: Marti, it works!!! It was set as "ON for some". After I changed it to "ON for everyone", I can see the add-on in the spreadsheet. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

@marti kindly gave me the answer.

> Click to the app row in [the admin tool](https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/gmail/marketplace/domaininstall), then click Distribution and make sure that > it's ON for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the Add-on is actually enabled for your organization unit. The easiest to do that is to enable it for everyone:

1. Go to [the Google Admin's Domain install Google Workspace Marketplace apps](https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/gmail/marketplace/domaininstall) and click to the app that you want.
2. Click to `Distribution`.
3. Set as `ON for everyone`.